# Showing that inequality for $|\sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha + y}| \leq k|x-y|$ (where $x,y>0$, $\alpha>1$ and $0 \leq k < 1$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

So I am trying to show that $\sqrt{\alpha + x}$ is a contraction mapping on the interval $[0, \infty)$ (where $\alpha>1$). It is my understanding that I need only show the inequality: $$|\sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha + y}| \leq k|x-y|$$ (where $x,y>0$, $\alpha>1$ and $0 \leq k < 1$)

To do so.

However I am having a really hard time coming up with it. Or even:
$$|\sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha + y}| \leq |x-y|$$ (Which I assumed perhaps would give me some help in developing a k dependent upon $\alpha$ which I believe is the ultimate goal here.)

I have had no luck thus far though. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Use
$$
\sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha + y} = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{\alpha + x} + \sqrt{\alpha + y}}
$$
and then find a lower bound for the denominator.

Alternatively, find a upper bound for the derivative of
$f(x) = \sqrt{\alpha + x}$ and use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Elegant. It's always the little things that I have trouble coming up with. If you are curious about an application to this, it is a way to prove that x = $\sqrt{\alpha + x}$ has a solution (that is to say that $f(x) = \sqrt{\alpha + x}$ has a point where $f(x) = x$ at exactly $\frac{1+sqrt(1+4\alpha)}{2}$

Comment: @LukeNelson: OK, but what is the point if you can compute the solution explicitly? – (It would also follow from the intermediate value theorem, since the difference is negative for $x=0$ and positive for large $x$.)

Comment: Well the point would be the same if you solved it explicitly. But the point is that It is a good example for the Contraction Mapping Principle that can easily be verified with some simple algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left| \sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha +y} \right| =\left| \frac{x-y}{ \sqrt{\alpha + x} + \sqrt{\alpha +y} } \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha + x} + \sqrt{\alpha +y}} \left| x-y \right|
$$
since $x,y>=0$ we have $ 0< \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha + x} + \sqrt{\alpha +y}} <= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\alpha}} <1 $
thus $\left| \sqrt{\alpha + x} - \sqrt{\alpha +y} \right| <= k \left| x-y \right| $